Formula to find missing serial numbers
Google Sheet Link
PART 1

INPUT:



STUDIO
FIN YEAR
NUMBER




A
X-X
3


A
X-X
1


A
O-O
8


B
X-X
1


B
X-X
2


C
X-X
1


B
O-O
4


B
X-X
3


A
X-X
5


C
X-X
2


C
X-X
3


A
O-O
1


A
O-O
2


A
O-O
2


A
O-O
4


C
O-O
1


C
O-O
1



OUTPUT: (In a single cell)
MISSING NUMBERS:
A: (O-O): 3,5,6,7 (X-X): 2,4
B: (O-O): 1,2,3
Explanation:
For "STUDIO" A in "FIN YEAR" X-X there are numbers 2,4 missing, similarly for O-O 3,5,6,7.
For "STUDIO" B in "FIN YEAR" X-X there is no number missing but for O-O 1,2,3 (So only (O-O) is displayed).
For "STUDIO" C in "FIN YEAR" X-X & O-O there is no missing number. (So C: is not displayed).
NOTES:
Numbers start from 1 for each "FIN YEAR" for each "STUDIO".
Numbers can repeat any number of time.
Every input is random, there is no order for any columns.
How can I write formula to achieve the given output?
Part 2
I would like to add to this formula in case where the "NUMBER" column cells contains one or more than one numbers:


Maybe this helps:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(a, A2:A20, b, B2:B20, c, C2:C20, 
 p, "max(Col3) where Col3>1 group by Col1,Col2 label max(Col3)''", 
 q, "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1",
 f, FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY({a&":đ("&b&"):¤×", {b,c}}, "select Col1,"&p, ),, 1)&
 BYROW(QUERY({a,b,c}, "select "&p, ), LAMBDA(c, MAKEARRAY(1,c,LAMBDA(c,r,r))))), 
 SUBSTITUTE("MISSING NUMBERS:Đ"&TEXTJOIN(, 1, "Đ"&TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(
 REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(QUERY(FILTER(f, 
 NOT(COUNTIF({a&":đ("&b&"):¤×"&c}, f))), "where not Col1 ends with '×'", )&",", "×"), 
 q),,9^9))), "\s|,$", ), "¤", " "), "đ"), q),,9^9))), "Đ", CHAR(10))))



Update:
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(z, A2:C20, i, SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(,BYROW(FILTER(z, INDEX(z,,1)<>""), 
 LAMBDA(r,JOIN(",",REDUCE(";",r,LAMBDA(c,cc,FLATTEN(FLATTEN(c)&","&SPLIT(cc,",")))))))),";,",)),","), 
 a, INDEX(i,,1), b, INDEX(i,,2), c, INDEX(i,,3), 
 p, "max(Col3) where Col3>1 group by Col1,Col2 label max(Col3)''", 
 q, "select max(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1",
 f, FLATTEN(INDEX(QUERY({a&":đ("&b&"):¤×", {b,c}}, "select Col1,"&p, ),, 1)&
 BYROW(QUERY({a,b,c}, "select "&p, ), LAMBDA(c, MAKEARRAY(1,c,LAMBDA(c,r,r))))), 
 SUBSTITUTE("MISSING NUMBERS:Đ"&TEXTJOIN(, 1, "Đ"&TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(
 REGEXREPLACE(FLATTEN(TRIM(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(QUERY(FILTER(f, 
 NOT(COUNTIF({a&":đ("&b&"):¤×"&c}, f))), "where not Col1 ends with '×'", )&",", "×"), 
 q),,9^9))), "\s|,$", ), "¤", " "), "đ"), q),,9^9))), "Đ", CHAR(10))))



Here's 2 methods that you can use in finding missing numbers:
Method 1: Google Sheets Formula
=let(
studio, "A",
arr, sort(filter(A2:C, A2:A=studio),2,0),
arr_x, torow(unique(filter(arr, index(arr,,2)="X-X"))),
arr_o, torow(unique(filter(arr, index(arr,,2)="O-O"))),
find_x, IFNA(join(",", torow(filter(sequence(max(arr_x),1,1), countif(arr_x,sequence(max(arr_x),1,1))=0))),"No Missing"),
find_o, IFNA(join(",", torow(filter(sequence(max(arr_o),1,1), countif(arr_o,sequence(max(arr_o),1,1))=0))),"No Missing"),
output, map(unique(index(arr,,2)), vstack(find_x,find_o), lambda(a,b,concat(concat(a,": "), b))),
join(char(10), "MISSING NUMBERS:", concat(studio,":"), output)
)

Note: If you use Google Sheets formula you need to take note of two constraints: (1) You need to manually input the Studio letter inside the formula or use a dropdown to select the Studio letter. (2) If you will add a new Studio letter, you need to have both X-X and O-O pairs.
Output:

Method 2: Google Apps Script
    function missingNumbers(data) {
      // map studio letters
      const letters = [... new Set(data.map(x => x[0][0]))] 
    
      return "MISSING NUMBERS:\n\n" + letters.map((l) => {
      //filters Fin Year
      const uniqueFinYear = [... new Set(data.filter(x => x[0][0] == l).map(x => x[1]))];
    
        //check sequence of number
        const res = uniqueFinYear.map(x => data.filter(d => d[1] == x).filter(d => d[0] == l))
          .map(x => {
            return x.map(y => y[2]).sort((a, b) => a - b).map((d, i, arr) => d + 1 == arr[i + 1] || d == arr[i + 1])
              .filter((x, i, arr) => arr.length == 1 && x == false ? true : i !== arr.length - 1 && x == false)[0] == false && x
          }).filter(x => x);
    
        return res.map((x) => {
          if (x.length > 0) {
            const newArr = Array.from({ length: Math.max(...x.map(x => x[2])) }, (_, index) => index + 1);
            return `${[... new Set(x.map(x => x[0]))]}: (${[... new Set(x.map(x => x[1]))]}): ${newArr.map(z => [... new Set([... new Set(x.map(x => x[2]).sort((a, b) => a - b))]
              .map(y => y != z && z))].length == 1 && [... new Set([... new Set(x.map(x => x[2]).sort((a, b) => a - b))]
                .map(y => y != z && z))]).flat().filter(d => d).join(',')}  `;
          }
        }).join('');
      }).join(" \n");
    }

Add the code above in Extension > Apps Script. Then call the function name missingNumbers in E2 cell. This will function as custom formula.
Output:

References:

Let

Join

Sort

Map

Find missing numbers (where the formula's logic was based on)




Here's one approach you may test out:
=iferror(let(Λ,map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,join(",",let(Σ,sequence(maxifs(C:C,A:A,a,B:B,b)),ifna(filter(Σ,isna(xmatch(Σ,filter(C:C,A:A&B:B=a&b))))))))),
 Γ,unique(filter({A2:A&":","("&B2:B&"): "&Λ},Λ<>"")), Ξ,index(Γ,,1), join(char(10),vstack("MISSING NUMBERS:",,map(unique(Ξ),lambda(x,concat(x&" ",join(" ",filter(index(Γ,,2),Ξ=x)))))))),"-_-")



I have added a part 2 in my question, it would be great if you could give the formula this too!
